# i18n for rails works in dev not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

The i18n is configured in the rails 3.0.3 project  :

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

In my dev environnement, everything works fine with price in € and text (like next previous from will_paginate) correctly displayed.

In production environnement, everything is in english and in $.

Where can i found the problem of my i18n ?

What am I missing in i18n in production?

More Info:

On the production server in the rails console production :

```
irb(main):002:0> I18n.config.default_locale
=> :fr
```

2Nd Edit

Is there a way to  display I18n properties or config in a debug or in a view?

Comment: have you looked in `config/environments/production.rb` if the default locale was changed here ?

Comment: I checked it, no problem there.

Comment: have you enabled any option to get the locale from client browser settings ? had the same problem, because my browser was set to english. If not, sorry but i don't know.

Comment: nope, tested on different computers.

Comment: Check I18n.locale see if it has been assigned another locale (en).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is related to this bug: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/1fe3e88f9fe73177/ .

> 18n.locale is called before the config.i18n.default_locale is 
>   propagated to the I18n class.

I will try to also change it in config/initializers/locale.rb.  According to 2.2 Optional: Custom I18n Configuration Setup in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html, you should also change it in config/initializers/locale.rb .  Hope this will fix it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Resolved by adding `config.i18n.locale = :fr` in addition of the default `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr` in my application.rb

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with rails admin. But I believe it is the same with any Rails app
At the beginning I have set locale statically in application.eb.
Later I have solve this be removing this a from application.rb

```
if ENV['language']
  config.i18n.default_locale = ENV['language']
else
  config.i18n.default_locale = :he
end
```

And just leaving this in rails_admin/application_controller.rb
(or just application_controller.rb for regular rails app)

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || 'he'
end

def default_url_options
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

Also a nice tuturial on how to set i18n locale based on Url:
https://dev.to/morinoko/setting-up-i18n-for-rails-with-locales-from-url-params-38pg